# If input `startTime` and `endTime` exists in between stored `startTime` and `endTime` user will unable to create In laravel8

Tags: mysql, laravel, time, where-clause

According to my `schedules` table:

when I am selecting a doctor and a day, Iam getting this result

```
//this query is executing when selecting
$schedule = Schedule::where('doctor_id', $request->doctor_id)->where('day', $request->day)->get();

[
  {
    "day": "sunday",
    "start_time": "10:00:00 am",
    "end_time": "02:00:00 pm"
  },
  {
    "day": "sunday",
    "start_time": "03:00:00 pm",
    "end_time": "06:00:00 pm"
  }
]
```

Now, when user will try to create another schedule for same doctor on same day between those time range, user will be restricted from creating.

Is there any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: I think you're giving us very little to work with. Laravel doesn't just randomly show messages. You must have set that as a ***validation message*** in your controller, custom validation rule or Form Request class.

Comment: @ steven7mwesigwa
I make this things for messages just i need the query or the procedure to restrict user from creating a new schedule. The message is for better understand.

Answer (score 0):

For the given start_time and end_time to check the time between existing time we can write a sql query like below,

```
$schedules = Schedule::where('doctor_id', $request->doctor_id)->where('day', $request->day)
                       ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->whereBetween('start_time', [$request->start_time, $request->end_time])->orWhere(function ($q) use ($request){
                        $q->where('start_time', '<=', $request->start_time);
                        $q->where('end_time', '>=',  $request->end_time);
                    });
                    $query->orWhereBetween('end_time',  [$request->start_time, $request->end_time]);

                })->get();

This piece of code works fine for me.
```